# Issue with Hadoop tasklog

Tags: hadoop

I want to use the Hadoop web interface to browse task logs. I can navigate to where it gives the option of 'Last 4KB, Last 8KB, All'. However, if I click on one of these, the URL gets messed up and the hostname of the machine running hadoop is replaced with 'localhost'

So specifically, the URL looks like this:

```
http://localhost:50060/tasklog?attemptid=attempt_201301152149_0001_m_000000_0&start=-4097
```

but it should look like this:

```
http://my.machine.com:50060/tasklog?attemptid=attempt_201301152149_0001_m_000000_0&start=-4097
```

Note that if I manually type over localhost with my.machine.com, then I can browse the task logs as expected.

I've looked over all my configuration files and can't figure out why this one thing doesn't work properly.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To browse the task logs through web UI by cliking on "4KB", "8KB", or "All" you have to add the corresponding machines to your /etc/hosts file. To browse the task logs of "my.machine.com" you have to add "my.machine.com" to /etc/hosts file.